# Model not null only when all properties have value

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2 for my API and Angular 4.4.2 for the front end.

I have a model class that has 8 string properties, but only one of them is required. My model gets bound only if all the model properties have value. When I post the data, I make sure I send empty strings and not `null` values, but still my model is `null` if even one property doesn't have a value.

With MVC you'd have this problem if the properties in the JSON object and the model have different names, but not if the strings are empty or even `null`.

The C# model class :

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }  // reusing the same model for edit and setting this to 0 when posting a new customer
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactSurname { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactMail { get; set; }
}
```

The action signature:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> PostCustomer([FromBody] CustomerModel model)
```

The Angular TS code that makes the post:

```
postCustomer() {
    this.createCustomer();
    if (this.edit) {
        this.customerService.editCustomer(this.customer).subscribe(() => {
                this.dialogRef.close();
            },
            reject => {
                console.log(reject);
            });
    } else {
        this.customerService.postCustomer(this.customer).subscribe(() => {
                this.dialogRef.close();
            },
            reject => {
                console.log(reject);
            });
    }
}   

createCustomer() {
    const customer = this.customerForm.value;  // using reactive forms
    this.customer = new Customer(this.edit ? this.customer.id : 0,
            customer.title,
            customer.address,
            customer.phone,
            customer.mail,
            customer.contactName,
            customer.contactSurname,
            customer.contactPhone,
            customer.contactMail
        );  

}
```

The post call:

```
  postCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`/Api/Customer/Post`, customer);
}
```

The `Request payload`

```
{"id":0,"title":"ssss","address":"","phone":"","mail":"","contactName":"","contactSurname":"","contactPhone":"","contactMail":""}
```

Comment: could you reproduce problem doing raw POST via curl, Fiidler etc ? I cannot see such behavior and think that maybe you have a problem with your request construction, not model binding. Could you show how you do post?

Comment: It seems that your model properties starts with uppercase and the properties in web are in lowercase. When you *return* a jsonresult from a controller the behavior has changed with aspnetcore and the uppercase properties will be converted to lowercase (see: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194). I'm not sure this works for model binding; that the web client's posted lowercase objcet properties are bound to the uppercase model?

Comment: @Set I just reproduced the same result with `Postman` and added the post call I make in my angular service. @mortb the binding works if all properties are populated, so the issue is not that, but I'm guessing it has something to do with serialization

Comment: Might be worth also showing the request body, etc, in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: I just added the payload

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this by setting up a default ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 project but the model is not `null` and has empty string values as expected.

Comment: I can't locate whether the problem is with angular or asp.net core

Comment: @KirkLarkin I just tried the same on a new app and I got `null`